# C# How to load a Canvas with XML

Tags: c#, xml, wpf, canvas, xml-deserialization

my problem is that I can't figure out how to load a Canvas type object from an XML file. I hope you can help me.

This is what I was trying, I'll show you the code of how I'm doing the serialization too, just in case I did something wrong.

```
private void SaveButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{

    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

    sfd.FileName = "untitled";
    sfd.Filter = "XML Files(*.xml) | *.xml | Text Files(*.txt) | *.txt | All Files(*.*) | *.*  ";

    sfd.ShowDialog();

    MainWindow mainWindow = new MainWindow();

    SerializeToXML(mainWindow, designSpace, 96, sfd.FileName);

      mainWindow.Close();


}

public static void SerializeToXML(MainWindow window, Canvas canvas, int dpi, string filename)
{

    string mystrXAML = XamlWriter.Save(canvas);

    FileStream filestream = File.Create(filename);
    StreamWriter streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
    streamwriter.Write(mystrXAML);
    streamwriter.Close();
    filestream.Close();
}





private void LoadButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var fileContent = string.Empty;
    OpenFileDialog ofd = new OpenFileDialog();
    ofd.InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
    ofd.Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
    ofd.FilterIndex = 2;
    ofd.RestoreDirectory = true;

     ofd.ShowDialog();


    var fileStream = ofd.OpenFile();
    string boi = ofd.FileName;

    // Create an instance of the XmlSerializer specifying type.
    XmlSerializer serializer =
    new XmlSerializer(typeof(Canvas));

    // Create a TextReader to read the file. 
    FileStream fs = new FileStream(boi, FileMode.Open);
    TextReader reader = new StreamReader(fs);

    // Use the Deserialize method to restore the object's state.
    designSpace = (Canvas)serializer.Deserialize(reader);



}
```

The app works well until I try to load an XML file, that's when this exception pops out:

> ```
> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Error to reflect type System.Windows.Controls.Canvas'.'
>
> NotSupportedException: Can not serialize the member
> System.Windows.Input.InputBinding.Command type
> System.Windows.Input.ICommand because it's an interface.
> ```

Comment: Wow, so many things wrong with the question. First, no [mcve]. Second, you apparently didn't bother to do a search on the "can not serialize the member...because it's an interface" error, because there's already plenty of help on SO and the web on that error. Third, "load" means deserializing, but all you've shown here is the serializing (which is "save", not "load")...i.e. not only is there no [mcve], there's not _any_ code related to what you're actually asking about. Fourth, the premise that you can just write a WPF `Canvas` object out and read back in is deeply flawed.

Comment: Bottom line: your basic strategy here is completely wrong, both in the way the question is asked, and in the way the code feature is being implemented. You should use the search tools available to you and study what features are available in .NET for XAML-specific serialization/deserializing. You can't just serialize your WPF UI graph to any old format; you'll need the support of WPF to create XAML that can be loaded later.

Answer (score 0):

I did

in Saving:

```
string xml = XamlWriter.Save(cssave);
using (StreamWriter fl = new StreamWriter(path, false))
{
    fl.Write(xml);
}
```

In Loading:

```
string xml = File.ReadAllText(currpath);
//Convert string to stream
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(xml);
MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray);
Canvas cs = (Canvas)XamlReader.Load(stream);
csmain.Children.Add(cs);
```